# Two Table Problems

Tags: tables, threeparttable

We can't figure out how to remove "Game", so there is only two columns. We don't know how to make a new line to the left with "1. analyze" (the letters should turn into the text int he box as well have a underline or something similar.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteLabel}[1]{#1}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
%\renewcommand\tabcolsep{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\centering}p{0.15\textwidth}>{\raggedright}m{0.68\textwidth}
    p{\dimexpr0.17\textwidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}
\toprule
\mc{Hypotese nr.}& \mc{Method} & \mc{Game}  \\
\midrule
1 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY \\
2 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY \\
3 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY \\
4 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & FALSIFY \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\vspace{-0.6em}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're trying to achieve? The "remove Game" part is not very clear... Also, if you have to submit the article, do you have any restrictions about which packages can be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know your purpose exactly, but this is a very bad table design.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable,multirow,graphicx}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteLabel}[1]{#1}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
%\renewcommand\tabcolsep{1pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}ccX@{}}
\cmidrule[1pt]{2-3}
  & Hypotese nr.& \mc{Method}  \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
\multirow{4}{*}[-1cm]{\rotatebox{90}{1. analyze}}& 1 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT   \\
& 2 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT   \\
& 3 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT   \\
& 4 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  \\
\cmidrule[1pt]{2-3}
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With 4 columns:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable,multirow,graphicx}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteLabel}[1]{#1}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
%\renewcommand\tabcolsep{1pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}c|cXl@{}}
\cmidrule[1pt]{2-4}
\mc{}  & Hypotese nr. & \mc{Method} &\mc{Game} \\
\cmidrule{2-4}
\multirow{4}{*}[-1cm]{\rotatebox{90}{1. analyze\quad\qquad}}& 1 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT & Some  \\
& 2 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT & Some  \\
& 3 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  & Some \\
& 4 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT & Some \\
\cmidrule[1pt]{2-4}
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) for 'this is a very bad table design' ;). I have no clue what anything is meant to refer to!

Comment: Thank you so much again Harish! :) Last question could you also show me how to add one more coloum, so I can see the difference in the code - because I have tried to create both this and a new one with three coloums, but that doesn't work!

Comment: @A.F. I am confused about what you actually want! You wanted to remove the last column isn't it?

Comment: I both want a table with 2 coloums + 1. analyze and one table with 3 coloums + 1. analyze. If I add "\multirow{4}{*}[-1cm]{\rotatebox{90}{1. analyze}}& " to the code you mentioned earlier, it wan't add 1. analyze. :) Hope that make sense, and sorry for inconvience!

Comment: If I add "& Game" and creates a new line and change \cmidrule[1pt]{2-3} to \cmidrule[1pt]{2-4} - its not gonna work.

Comment: @A.F. please see the update

Comment: looks really good. Thank you so much. Last but not least, Is it possible to make a vertical line from hypothesis 1-4? If it was a horizontal line I would use following function: \cmidrule[lr]{1-4}

Comment: @A.F. Like the last update?

Answer (score 3):

A slightly modified version of Harish Kumar's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/217882/27635).

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,right=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable,multirow,graphicx}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteSettings}{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\TPTnoteLabel}[1]{#1}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
%\renewcommand\tabcolsep{1pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}m{.4cm}cX@{}}
\cmidrule[1pt]{2-3}
  & Hypotese nr.& \mc{Method}  \\
\cmidrule{2-3}
\multirow{4}{.4cm}[-1cm]{1. a n a l y z e}
& 1 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT   \\
& 2 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT   \\
& 3 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT   \\
& 4 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT   \\
\multirow{4}{.4cm}[-1cm]{2. a n a l y z e}
& 5 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT   \\
& 6 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT   \\
& 7 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT   \\
& 8 & TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT  TEXT TEXT TEXT   \\
\cmidrule[1pt]{2-3}
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Last but not least, Is it possible to make a vertical line from hypothesis 1-4? If it was a horizontal line I would use following function: \cmidrule[lr]{1-4}

Comment: I don't understand where you want that line.